# ArcPy: Kernel Density Extend (Default + 5000 Meters)

Tags: arcpy, kernel-density, default, extend

I in my Kernel Density Loop i want the **Processing Extend** to be
**Default + 5000m**

Does anyone know how this might be done?

This is the Code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = r'C:\Users\lhark\Desktop\SHK\ArcGis_Proj_Canada\shapefiles'
outworkspace = r'C:\Users\lhark\Desktop\SHK\ArcGis_Proj_Canada\KernelDensity'
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses ()
for fc in fcList:
    outKDens = KernelDensity(fc,"NONE",500,500,"SQUARE_KILOMETERS","EXPECTED_COUNTS")
    outKDens.save(outworkspace + "/" + os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + "_kd.tif")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like this, since the default processing extent is based on the extent of the feature class.

```
for fc in fcList:
    fcext = arcpy.Describe(fc).extent
    env.extent = arcpy.Extent(fcext.XMin-5000,fcext.YMin-5000,fcext.XMax+5000,fcext.YMax+5000)
    outKDens = KernelDensity(fc,"NONE",500,500,"SQUARE_KILOMETERS","EXPECTED_COUNTS")
    outKDens.save(outworkspace + "/" + os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + "_kd.tif")
```